# Decode Encoded String

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I have a box that looks like this . I am trying to put it into a string like this

```
var t = ""
```

but whenever I try to do that, it automatically gets encoded into something that looks like this ðŸŸ©

Here is my code:

```
<div id="green" style="display: none;">ðŸŸ©</div>
```

Should Be

```
<div id="green" style="display: none;"></div>
```

How do I decode it? (This code is being uploaded to chrome://extensions if that helps. Thats why its changing I think)

Comment: how are you sending the html? is there a header missing including utf8?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to the `head` tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="green"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also why have you set display to none?

Comment: I set it to display none because I don't want the users to see the image, that was just for testing.

Comment: No, that was the answer, but now there is another issue which I will post in another question shortly

Answer (score -1):

The charset attribute specifies the character encoding for the HTML document.

The HTML5 specification encourages web developers to use the UTF-8 character set, which covers almost all of the characters and symbols in the world!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>

  <body>
    ...       
  </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer?

Comment: You must learn to respect other people answers not only putting -.
I will not answer your question because it is not adequate.